# GeoLite2 Country: CSV Format permalink - always returns Invalid license key, all other pemalinks work fine

Tags: geoip, maxmind, geolite2

looking for some help...

I cannot download the GeoLite2 Country: CSV Format from Maxmind using the permalink.

All of the other Geolite2 files using the permalinks and a valid key work fine.

I followed the instructions:

> `# Database URL https://download.maxmind.com/app/geoip_download?edition_id=GeoLite2-Country-CSV&license_key=YOUR_LICENSE_KEY&suffix=zip`

I replaced YOUR_LICENSE_KEY with a key I generated within my Maxmind account.

The result I get is 'Invalid license key'.

I've tested all of the other permalink downloads, and they all work with the key. Problem only affects the Country CSV one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How long after generating your license key did you attempt to download that file? Did you try to download it again after the successful attempts on other database downloads? I ask because it can take a minute or two for a new license key to be seen as valid.